# Convert given date to generic date format?

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I have to take an input date and convert it to generic date format.
For that I have created a function(not generic one) below is the sample code of the function.

```
public class ConvertTimestampFormat{
    public void evaluate(String dateInString) {
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(dateInString)) {

            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
            try {
                Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
                System.out.println(date);
                System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
     }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConvertTimestampFormat obj = new ConvertTimestampFormat();
        obj.evaluate("2014-06-14-12:58");
    }
}
```

Please correct if there is something wrong in the sample code.

Here I have hard coded the input date format `2014-06-14-12:58`. Here I will get different kind of date formats like `2014/06/14-12:58`, `2014-Mar-14-12:58` (In this way I will get 5 to 6 formats now). I thought of using if else to check the format then based on format writing separate code for each format. But it will fail if a new date format came in future.

My output format will be always should be as `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`.

Please suggest me generic way(generic function) to do this.

Comment: Be careful with _generic_, it the java world it means things like this `List<T>`, I think you mean _flexible_ more than generic don't you?

Comment: If you have two input date formats you'll need two date formatters for each type. Then you parse with the first, catch the exception and then parse with the second, if an exception is caught here then the input matches neither of the two formatters.

Comment: @superbob I agree with you it's kind of more than generic.

Comment: @Daniel Tung agreed that it both formatters didn't match the input is different from both the formats. Here again I need to add the format then only I will get the exact result. Further I need to keep on add the code all allow new formats. Is there a way to write a generic code to accept all possible formats.

Comment: you could pass 2 parameters to the method, 1 for the format and other for the actual date

Comment: See my answer, the Java 8 variant, you could add all the [predefined formats](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#predefined) proposed since Java 8 in the `FORMATTERS` array

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to do this. You either provide the formatter string with the date OR you hard code and chain (very ugly) every format you want to use. I suggest breaking the chained solution down into multiple methods.

Solution 1:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class ConvertTimestampFormat {

    private SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
    private Date dateObject;

    public void evaluate(String dateString, String dateFormat) {
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(dateString)) {

            SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
            try {
                dateObject = inputFormat.parse(dateString);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                //Parse failed. String does not match the formatter.
            }

            if(dateObject != null) {
                System.out.println(outputFormat.format(dateObject));
            }
        }
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConvertTimestampFormat obj = new ConvertTimestampFormat();
        obj.evaluate("2014-03-14-12:58", "yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm");
        obj.evaluate("2014-Mar-14-12:58", "yyyy-MMM-dd-hh:mm");
    }
}
```

The Ugly Solution:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class ConvertTimestampFormat {

    private SimpleDateFormat inputFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm");
    private SimpleDateFormat inputFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd-hh:mm");
    private SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
    private Date dateObject;

    public void evaluate(String dateInString) {
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(dateInString)) {

            try {
                dateObject = inputFormat1.parse(dateInString);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                try {
                    dateObject = inputFormat2.parse(dateInString);
                } catch (ParseException e1) {
                    //String didn't match either formatters. You'll want to do something about this!
                }
            }

            if(dateObject != null) {
                System.out.println(outputFormat.format(dateObject));
            }
        }
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConvertTimestampFormat obj = new ConvertTimestampFormat();
        obj.evaluate("2014-03-14-12:58");
        obj.evaluate("2014-Mar-14-12:58");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I had this solution in my mind just looking for better solution if there is one.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there seems not to be any "magical" way to handle all the possible dates formats in Java.

The best you could do, as suggested in another answer ([need flexible datetime conversion with joda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994086/need-flexible-datetime-conversion-with-joda)), is something like this:

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat[] FORMATTERS = new SimpleDateFormat[] {
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd-hh:mm"),
    [...]};

private static Date parseDate(String dateInString) {
    Date date = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < FORMATTERS.length; i++) {
        try {
            date = FORMATTERS[i].parse(dateInString);
            break;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // Nothing to do, try the next one
        }
    }
    return date;
}
```

To use this code, you just have to call `parseDate` with the date string.
To add a new format, add it to the `FORMATTERS` array.

This is not the prettiest code you could end up with. Handling code through exception and breaking loops can be a bad practice. See [link1](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl), [link2](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58237/are-break-and-continue-bad-programming-practices) about that.

To enhance your code, you could consider using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (Java <= 7) or Java 8 [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes: [DateTimeFormat](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)/[DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) with [LocalDateTime(joda)](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/index.html)/[LocalDateTime(java8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) that provide an [enhanced API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) over the standard/old ones:

*Using Java 8 java.time classes:*

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter[] FORMATTERS = new DateTimeFormatter[] {
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"),
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd-hh:mm"),
    [...]};

private static Optional<LocalDateTime> parseDate(String dateInString) {
    Optional<LocalDateTime> date = Optional.empty();
    for (int i = 0; i < FORMATTERS.length; i++) {
        try {
            date = Optional.of(LocalDateTime.parse(dateInString, FORMATTERS[i]));
            break;
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            // Nothing to do, try the next one
        }
    }
    return date;
}
```

I also added some [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) to handle the emptyness of the result if the `dateInString` cannot be parsed instead of `null` which is [bad](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare).

Answer (score 1):

you gave

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm")`;
```

so, the string should be like `obj.evaluate("2014-06-14 12:58");`

hardcoded string should be in exact pattern as mentioned inside `SimpleDateFormat()`

Comment: @Blip  yes it's typo as I mentioned in the question it's sample code.